# palindrome range in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am 15 days old to Python Learning and need your guidance for each and every step on the below code.
This code checks for largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

very sorry for the dumbest question.

````
largest_palindrome = 0
for x in range(999,100,-1):
    for y in range(x,100,-1):
        product = x*y
        check = str(x*y)
        if check ==  check[::-1]:
            if product > largest_palindrome:
                largest_palindrome = product
print(largest_palindrome) ```

 - Need clarification on the below:

for x in range(999,100,-1): #why is -1 introduced here. what is the range it is checking in (999,100,-1)
for y in range(x,100,-1): # why is x introduced in y loop. how much times it will check the range.
product = x*y
check = str(x*y)# why is string introduced here ?

if check ==  check[::-1]: # what does this line mean?
if product > largest_palindrome:
largest_palindrome = product

print(largest_palindrome)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for x in range(999,100,-1): #why is -1 introduced here. what is the range it is checking in (999,100,-1)

> Answer: x is iterating from 999 to 100, decreasing by 1 on each loop

for y in range(x,100,-1): # why is x introduced in y loop. how much times it will check the range.

> Answer: y is iterating from x (from upper loop) until 100. This loop
> will be running for each value of x from upper loop

check = str(x*y)# why is string introduced here ?

> Answer: converting the product from int to str so that we can reverse
> the number. Below is possible for string not for int, so it is
> converted to string

if check ==  check[::-1]: # what does this line mean?

> Answer: check[::-1] is the reverse string of chech. We check here if
> reversed string and non-reversed string are same (pallindrome if same)

Comment: Thanks Gopal very much. truly appreciate

Comment: from the above code where does it check if that is the largest palindrome ? also if I want to see all the palindrome, how should I modify the code.

Comment: Initially you assume arbitrary largest pallindrome with: largest_palindrome = 0[line 1]. Later on during the loop you check if you found another larger value than current, and if it does, it assigns the largest value to largest_palindrome [line 7-8]. If you want to see all pallindrome in before line 7 put this: print(product)